# How I can get the maximum memory size supported by a laptop or desktop machine?

Tags: delphi, winapi, wmi

I'm building a software using Delphi to get some hardware info, I need to get the maximum memory (RAM) size supported by a laptop or desktop machine using delphi, so far I was looking for a WinApi or WMI function to get that info, but I not found any info related to this. How I can get the maximum memory size supported by a laptop or desktop machine?

Comment: Please define precisely what you mean

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, I mean  "what's the max memory I can install into this machine".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [SMBIOS](http://dmtf.org/standards/smbios) to get that info, try reading the documentation about the [`Physical Memory Array (Type 16)`](http://dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.8.0.pdf) Table.  You can [parse and extract the SMBIOS tables manually](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/reading-the-smbios-tables-using-delphi/) or use a library like [TSMBIOS](http://code.google.com/p/tsmbios/).

try this sample which uses the TSMBIOS library.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes,
  SysUtils,
  uSMBIOS in '..\..\Common\uSMBIOS.pas';

function  GetMaxMemoryCapacity : UInt32;
Var
  SMBios : TSMBios;
  LPhysicalMemArr  : TPhysicalMemoryArrayInformation;
begin
  result:=0;
  SMBios:=TSMBios.Create;
  try
      if SMBios.HasPhysicalMemoryArrayInfo then
      for LPhysicalMemArr in SMBios.PhysicalMemoryArrayInfo do
      begin
        if LPhysicalMemArr.RAWPhysicalMemoryArrayInformation.MaximumCapacity<>$80000000 then
          result:=result+(LPhysicalMemArr.RAWPhysicalMemoryArrayInformation.MaximumCapacity*LPhysicalMemArr.RAWPhysicalMemoryArrayInformation.NumberofMemoryDevices)
        else
          result:=result+((LPhysicalMemArr.RAWPhysicalMemoryArrayInformation.ExtendedMaximumCapacity div 1024)*LPhysicalMemArr.RAWPhysicalMemoryArrayInformation.NumberofMemoryDevices);
      end
      else raise Exception.Create('No Physical Memory Array Info was found');
  finally
   SMBios.Free;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    Writeln(Format('Max Memory Capacity installable %d kb',[GetMaxMemoryCapacity]));
 except
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Comment: The TSMBIOS can use the WMI (MSSmBios_RawSMBiosTables) or the WinApi (GetSystemFirmwareTable) in Windows, for Linux access the `/dev/mem` device file and parse the info, you can try the source code here http://code.google.com/p/tsmbios/source/browse/trunk/Common/uSMBIOS.pas

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394348%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class and the MaxCapacity property.

> MaxCapacity : Maximum memory size (in bytes) installable for this
>   particular memory array. If the size is unknown, the property is given
>   a value of 0 (zero).

This property can return the size in bytes or kilobytes, so you must check the [`Units`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) qualifier of the property before to use it.

Try this sample

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}


uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;

function  GetQualifierValue(Const NameSpace, ClassName, PropName, QualifName : string) :string;
const
  wbemFlagUseAmendedQualifiers = $00020000;
Var
  Properties        : OleVariant;
  Qualifiers        : OleVariant;
  rgvarProp         : OleVariant;
  rgvarQualif       : OleVariant;
  objSWbemLocator   : OleVariant;
  objSWbemObjectSet : OleVariant;
  objWMIService     : OleVariant;
  EnumProps         : IEnumVariant;
  EnumQualif        : IEnumVariant;
  pceltFetched      : Cardinal;
  Lindex            : Integer;
begin
  Result:='';
  objSWbemLocator  := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  objWMIService    := objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', NameSpace, '', '');
  objSWbemObjectSet:= objWMIService.Get(ClassName, wbemFlagUseAmendedQualifiers);
  Properties := objSWbemObjectSet.Properties_;
  EnumProps         := IUnknown(Properties._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while EnumProps.Next(1, rgvarProp, pceltFetched) = 0 do
  begin
    if SameText(rgvarProp.Name, PropName) then
    begin
      Qualifiers      := rgvarProp.Qualifiers_;
      EnumQualif     := IUnknown(Qualifiers._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
      while EnumQualif.Next(1, rgvarQualif, pceltFetched) = 0 do
      begin
        if SameText(QualifName, rgvarQualif.Name) then
        begin
           if not VarIsNull(rgvarQualif.Value)  then
            Result:=rgvarQualif.Value;
           Break;
        end;
        rgvarQualif:=Unassigned;
      end;
      Break;
    end;
    rgvarProp:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;


function  GetMaxMemoryCapacity : UInt32;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
  UnitsName     : string;
begin;
  Result:=0;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
  UnitsName     := GetQualifierValue('root\CIMV2','Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray','MaxCapacity','Units');
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT MaxCapacity,MemoryDevices FROM Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray','WQL',$00000020);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    if SameText('kilobytes', UnitsName) then
     Result:=Result+(UInt32(FWbemObject.MaxCapacity)*UInt32(FWbemObject.MemoryDevices))
    else
     Result:=Result+((UInt32(FWbemObject.MaxCapacity) div 1024)*UInt32(FWbemObject.MemoryDevices));
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It gives 4 GB on my computer, where 16 GB is installed. Is the value supposed to be multiplied with `MemoryDevices`?